# open .dv file from imovie '08 into imovie '09

Tags: imovie

I have used iMovie '08 on a 2010 MBP to capture video from a Digital8 recorder through the Firewire port. It created this 25 GB file:

```
~/Movies/iMovie Events.localized/New Event 7-27-19/clip-135-02-05 05;27;15.dv
```

I have coped my entire `~/Movies` directory to an external harddrive and moved it to a more modern MBP running iMovie '09.

Is there a way to import the `.dv` file into iMovie '09? When I use the `Import iOS iMovie Projects` menu option I can navigate to the `.dv` file but it appears greyed out.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7990758

Comment: For the sake of preserving the original footage, I suggest converting the original footage to a modern video format. Try opening the .dv files in quicktime player and export them. It should allow you to export the footage as an mp4 which is supported by most all software.

Comment: Thanks @www139 - simply dragging the `.dv` file from the Finder to the iMovie project workarea works.